# Haven't {eaten / ate}?

Tags: past-participles, perfect-constructions

While chatting with somebody, I first used *haven't eaten*, then I thought that it was wrong, and switched to *haven't ate*.

Apparently, *haven't ate* is the one which is wrong.

Can someone explain the logic behind this? **Verb tenses** are still something I confuse a lot.

Comment: Even though it is not related to the question but 'I often use have in place of eat', Have you had lunch yet? I will have it later.

Comment: *Haven't ate* is certainly something people say, but it's not Standard English.   You might hear it, for example, in [AAVE](http://public.wsu.edu/~gordonl/S2003/326/SAE_AAVE.htm).

Comment: If you go to Oald you'll see that the three basic forms are eat/ate/eaten.  "ate" is pronounced /et/ in BrE and /eit/ in AmE. You find the basic forms under the headline "verb forms".

Comment: I have got an Aussie friend and he always says _I must have ate something wrong._

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The principle parts of the verb *eat* are:

> `eat     infinitive and present`
>   `ate     past`
>   `eaten   past participle`
>   `eating  present participle`

Accordingly, *perfect* constructions are formed with *have* + ***eaten***:

> I have ***eaten***, you had ***eaten***, he will have ***eaten***, &c

*Passive* constructions are formed with *be* + ***eaten***:

> We are ***eaten***, you were ***eaten***, they will be ***eaten***, &c

*Progressive* (*continuous*) constructions are formed with *be* + ***eating***:

> I am ***eating***, you were ***eating***, she will be ***eating***, &c

You will occasionally hear *et* for the past, and even for the past participle but in US speech these are strictly non-standard dialect forms.

Comment: The pronunciation *et* for simple past is pretty common in SE UK at least. I don't think of that pronunciation as being "non-standard dialectal" - just when it's used as a past participle, which is much less common (though certainly not *uncommon*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I will correct that. I was under the impression that /et/ had died out of RP in the early years of the 20th century.

Comment: "We are eaten, you were eaten, they will be eaten" are grammatically correct, but spoken only by people faced with cannibalism or becoming animal food.  Thus, "we are eaten" could never be said, except by a ghost.  "You were eaten" would involve talking to human remains.  "They will be eaten" could be both bad and good news (possibly implies a postponement for us).

Answer (score 6):

*haven't eaten* is correct. This is the present perfect form, which in this case describes an action or state occurring in the present or recent past.
For example:

> I have just eaten the salad.
>   I haven't eaten the sandwich.

On the other hand *ate* is the simple past form, so a helper verb cannot be used. It describes an action or state that occurred in the past. For example:

> I ate the salad.
>   I kicked the ball.

Answer (score 5):

*Ate* is the simple past of the verb *to eat*, whereas *eaten* is the past participle.

As you are using the auxiliary *have* for the present perfect, you are bound to use the past participle. The simple past form is to be used independently for finished actions or situations.